# Adding share your thoughts about the problem and any attempts to solve it to the "How do I ask a good question"-page for self-study questions

Tags: discussion, help-center

My proposal is simple. Should we add "share your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it" to the [How do I ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)-page for all self-study related questions (e.g homework questions, a routine question from a textbook, a question from a test used for class or self-study, ...) ?

Comment: Can you explain how the paragraph entitled "Search, and research" isn't sufficient? Otherwise it's not really clear what you suggest.

Comment: That paragraph start with "Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/search) _before_ asking your question?" with a link to our search page, leading to suggest that seaching for an answer is _the_ core ingredient in the research part. I think it is because this is a standard text that is also showed on other stack exchanges such as cross validated. My suggestion is to add some specific guidelines considering self-study questions on our ask page, in the same way as stack overflow also has some specific programming related guidelines on their ask page.

Comment: I haven't thought this through, but Instinctively I support this. After all, it is one of the more common obstacles the newbies run into. If not the most common.

Comment: There is nothing much to be said against improving the documentation, however, the reasoning is a bit astonishing. It is not that we have many users posting: I tried to search the site  and found [this] or  did not find [that].

Comment: I think this is a relatively noble cause that will have approximately zero measurable impact - I would be surprised if even, say, 5% of the questions that get closed for showing no effort have read the 'how to ask a good question' page.

Comment: I think that it would be better to add this to the close reasons so we don't have to click through that dialogue twice every time...

Comment: also related http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/add-give-references-to-how-do-i-ask-good-questions-page maybe we can combine the two

Comment: @Newb: That is precisely what I don't understand, and apparently they think it is **not worth** having such as a major reason on its own!

Comment: Clicking that dialogue twice truly isn't that much effort and they only have access to changing the off-topic reasons list.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's a good idea to try to condense the entire [How to ask a homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) FAQ into a single share-your-thoughts sentence. It's more complex than that.

If the how-to-ask page is site customizable at all (it doesn't look so to me), it would be better to reference the FAQ directly, with an new section such as

> ### Homework problems
>
> If you're asking about homework (or something similar to that, such as an exercise in self-study material that the author expected the reader to be able to solve on his own), follow the advice in [How to ask a homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).